# How to update an user as admin in Firebase

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I've a web application and I want, as the *Admin user*, to be able to update the information like `displayName` and `photoURL` of other users with `Firebase` authentication.

Typically if we want to update the user information we use `firebase.User.updateProfile()` *but that just works for the current user*, and, as I've mentioned before, I'm logged in with an admin account and I want to update other users' profiles.

My question is: Is there a function to which you can pass the `uid` and the information of an user to be updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do so with the [`Firebase Admin SDK`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user):

```dart
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  email: "modifiedUser@example.com",
  phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
  emailVerified: true,
  password: "newPassword",
  displayName: "Jane Doe",
  photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
  disabled: true
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of `userRecord`.
    console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error updating user:", error);
    });
```

Comment: Do I have to use the admin SDK to updateUser? I know how to `auth().currentUser.updateProfile`  but that is only for displayName and photoURL... How can i update current users phoneNumber?

Comment: If you are doing it as an admin, you have to use it via admin sdk `updateUser`. If you are doing it as a user, you can use `updatePhoneNumber` API but that will go through the regular verification flow (OTP sent to user's phone, etc).